# Converting Pandas DataFrame to tkinter object

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a Pandas' DataFrame GUI in tkinter that would update the moment the user changes the value of the cell (each cell is an Entry). I thought that converting the DataFrame into tkinter variables (tk.StringVar,  tk.IntVar...) would be the best way to achieve that.

My problem:
I am not sure how to convert dataframe into those objects. I tried using the astype function, but it doesn't seem to convert the type.

My questions:
1) how to convert dataframe into tkinter variables?

2) is converting dataframe into ttkinter variables the best way to make the dataframe update instantly?

Comment: for every element in row and column you have to do `var = StringVar(value=df[row,col])` or `var = StringVar() ; var.set(df[row,col]))` and keep in standard list. I think `pandas` can't use `StringVar` as `dtype`

Comment: you could put values directly to `Entry`, and `bind()` event to `Entry`  which will execute function everytime something change in `Entry`. This function could copy value from `Entry` to `dataframe`. Or you can add `Button` (ie. with text `"Save"`) and copy data from all `Entry` to `dataframe` only when you click button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `pandas` can't use `StringVar` as `dtype`.

You would have to get every element in dataframe and create separated `var = StringVar(value=df[row,col])` (or `var = StringVar() ; var.set(df[row,col]))`) and keep them in standard list.

But you could put values directly to `Entry`, and `bind()` event to `Entry` which will execute function everytime something change in `Entry` or you press `Enter`.  This function could copy value from `Entry` to `dataframe`.

---

**EDIT:** example code

It changes value in `dataframe` when you click `Enter` (or `Enter` on keypad) in any `Entry`.

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [5,6,7], [101,102,103]])

# --- functions ---

def change(event, row, col):
    # get value from Entry
    value = event.widget.get()
    # set value in dataframe
    df.iloc[row,col] = value
    print(df)

# --- main --    

root = tk.Tk()

# create entry for every element in dataframe

rows, cols = df.shape

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        e = tk.Entry(root)
        e.insert(0, df.iloc[r,c])
        e.grid(row=r, column=c)
        # ENTER 
        e.bind('<Return>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: change(event,y,x))
        # ENTER on keypad
        e.bind('<KP_Enter>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: change(event,y,x))

# start program

root.mainloop()
```

---

To change value in dataframe with every key press use `<KeyRelease>`

(it works when you press `Ctrl+V` too, so you can paste data from clipboard)

```
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        e = tk.Entry(root)
        e.insert(0, df.iloc[r,c])
        e.grid(row=r, column=c)
        e.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: changed(event, y,x))
```

---

**EDIT:** example as [class DataFrameEdit(tk.Frame)](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/dataframe-entry-frame)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you